# fetch records from a field which is not in date time format

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a varchar field name meeting_date which stores date like mm/dd/yyyy as in 
12/25/2016 and now i try to fetch results from db where month and year match the meeting_date from a form request as below but i get no result

```
$y =$_REQUEST['y'];
$m =$_REQUEST['m'];
$date = "$y/$m";

$table = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM records WHERE meeting = 'Yes' AND (meeting_date LIKE '%".$date."%') ORDER BY id DESC");
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($table);
```

appreciate your time and help

Comment: Use `DATE_FORMAT` like this `DATE_FORMAT(meeting_date, '%Y/%m') = $date`

Comment: @ProfessorZoom that does not work because its a string not stored in datetime format

Comment: Did you tried it? I did and it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
meeting_date LIKE '%".$m."/%"."%/".$y."%'.
```

You have day between month and year.

It would be much better if you can change varchar field to date and format how it looks on site after query. Then your query would look like:

```
MONTH(meeting_date) = $m AND YEAR(meeting_date) = $y
```

Comment: the second solution i will give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input is a string in format dd/mm/yyyy you could use a str_to_date and a date_format

```
mysql_query("SELECT * 
            FROM records
            WHERE meeting = 'Yes' 
            AND  date_format(str_to_date(meeting_date, '%d/%m/%Y' ), '%Y/%m')  
                        =  date_format(str_to_date ($date, '%d/%m/%Y') , '%Y/%m') 
            ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: ah this is also a nice solution. appreciate it

Comment: Well @johrampong   .. hope this could be useful

Comment: It indeed is helpful mate

Comment: well  then you  can rate as useful

Comment: ah yes totally forgot apologies